# Check a point whether it is inside the square/rectangle/polygon in ObjectiveC

Tags: objective-c

I's looking for simple(easy to implement algorithm) to check whether a point is inside the square/rectangle/polygon(convex)

I use CAShaperLayer to draw the polygon and I know there is **hittest** method in CAShaperLayer. For some reason, I don't allow to use **hittest**.

What I did so far:

I use a circle to approximate the polygon and check whether a point is inside the circle(choose three points and generate a circle since three point determine a circle).
The approximate method works but it is not accurate.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217578/point-in-polygon-aka-hit-test

Comment: Are all the shapes representable as UIBezierPaths?  If yes then use -containsPoint https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBezierPath/containsPoint: